# How the change the cte column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to get the CTE each column value stored in a variable then perform some operation on it. At last stored variable values into other table. But there are more than 10 records in a CTE so I am confused how i do this?

```
Declare @LineRead nvarchar(max)
;with cte(ID,RecordLine) as (
  select Id,RecordLine from [dbo].[WorkDataImport]
)
select @LineRead = RecordLine + 'TEmp' 
print LineRead
```

Result is

```
xyzaaddda Temp
```

I dont know why i get only one records.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using `SELECT` for variable assignation. 
SQL Server supports nonstandard assignment `SELECT` statement, which allows querying
data and assign multiple values obtained from the same row to multiple variables by using a single statement.

The assignment `SELECT` has predictable behavior when exactly one row qualifies. However, if the query has more than one qualifying row, the code doesn’t fail. The assignments take place per each qualifying row, and with each row accessed, the values from the current row overwrite the existing values in the variables. When the assignment SELECT finishes, the values in the variables are those from the last row that SQL Server happened to access.
That's why you are getting only one row.

Replace the `SELECT` with `SET` and the code will throw error as:
`SET @LineRead = RecordLine + 'TEmp'`

One way is to save all the rows from CTE to temp table and then perform the manipulations as:

```
;with cte(ID,RecordLine) as (
  select Id,RecordLine from [dbo].[WorkDataImport]
)
select  RecordLine + 'TEmp' as LineRead
into #Temp1
from cte

select * from  #Temp1
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZHI59262)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
;with mycte(ID,RecordLine) as (
  select Id,RecordLine from [dbo].[WorkDataImport]
)
select  RecordLine + 'TEmp' into #temp from mycte
```

THEN retrieve all the records from #temp(temp table)

```
select * from #temp
```